# Do self-reference variables have any applications in mathematics or even allowed in the first place?

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic

Let **x** be a variable whose value can be an element of the set of all real numbers.

```
... 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 ...
```

Let **x1**, **x2** be reference points in dimension x.

```
x1 = 2
x2 = x1 + 3

.. 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 ...
         x1       x2
```

Let **a** be a variable whose value is the distance between x1 and x2 in dimension x.

```
a = x2 - x1

.. 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 ...
         x1---a---x2
```

Summary and properties so far ...

```
x1 = 2 // independent variable (value is a constant).
x2 = x1 + a // dependent variable (value is not a constant).
a = x2 - x1 // dependent variable (value is not a constant).

.. 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 ...
         x1---a---x2
```

If **x2 = x1 + a** is expanded such that **a** is replaced with its value, the following would be expected:

```
x2 = x1 + a
x2 = x1 + (x2 - x1)
```

As one can see, **x2** is referencing itself in its value creating an infinite loop of variable substitution:

```
x2 = x1 + a
x2 = x1 + (x2 - x1)
x2 = x1 + ((x1 + a) - x1)
x2 = x1 + ((x1 + (x2 - x1)) - x1)
x2 = x1 + ((x1 + ((x1 + a) - x1)) - x1)
x2 = x1 + ((x1 + ((x1 + (x2 - x1)) - x1)) - x1)
...
```

Should the value of **a** be a constant value to prevent this substitution madness?

```
x1 = 2 // independent variable (value is a constant).
x2 = x1 + a // dependent variable (value is not a constant).
a = 3 // independent variable (value is now a constant).

.. 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 ...
         x1---a---x2

x2 = x1 + a
x2 = x1 + 3
x2 = 2 + 3
x2 = 5
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with infinite families of finite substitutions. Recursive structures do this all the time.

Comment: @CyclotomicField in this example, if a is not a constant value, then x2 will never know its absolute value.

Comment: You shouldn't know the value of a variable, that's the whole point of being a variable. I don't see the problem.

Comment: An equation is an equation is an equation and nothing more than an equation. I can tell you that $x_2 = x_1 + (x_2 - x_1)$ is a true equation without knowing anything more about $x_1$ and $x_2$ other than that they are real numbers (or some other type of object that adds and subtracts like real numbers). But an equation is not a definition.

Comment: @DavidK if equations are not definitions then, are they like proposals? And what would be a true definition, a constant value like a = 3?

Comment: A definition can **include** one or more equations.  For example, you might define something as "the real number $x$ such that (some equation involving $x$) is true."  This would be a good definition if it turns out that there is exactly one real number $x$ for which the equation is true.

Comment: An equation is just a comparison of two expressions. It's a kind of statement of fact. There are special symbols for "equals by definition", for example $:=$. But usually one just uses the word "define" or "definition" somewhere, for example, "Define $f(x) = x^2.$" But $3$ is already a perfectly good name for that particular constant, so it would be odd to define another name for it.

Comment: Also, an independent variable is usually **not** considered a constant, contrary to what you wrote, although sometimes we write some equations such as the simultaneous equations $x+y=5$ and $x-y=3$ and solve for the variables $x$ and $y,$ which ends up assigning particular values to the variables.